# Unable to infer closure type in the current context

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

On the 3rd line in the function below I get the following error:

> Unable to infer closure type in the current context

How do I fix this?

```
func fetchAllUsersImages() {
    print("inside func")
    self.ref.child("Posts").child(self.userID).child(self.postNum).observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in //error here

        var images: [URL] = []
        if let snapShotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: String] {

            for (_, value) in snapShotValue {
                if let imageURL = URL(string: value) {
                    print(imageURL, "image url here")
                    let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
                    let ImageObject = Image()
                    ImageObject.image = image
                    self.arrayOfImgObj.append(ImageObject)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I am unsure of what you mean by changing teh contant... which one? and teh other post you are refering to I do not see exacly how I could apply that

Comment: let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL) seems to be causeing it for soem reason @George_E

Comment: I did                         do {
                            let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
                            let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
                            let ImageObject = Image()
                            ImageObject.image = image
                            self.arrayOfImgObj.append(ImageObject)
                        } catch {
                            print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data")
                        }
and it worked provide as answer and i check it

Comment: I have used that comment and developed an explanation on why it didn't work - it is a **very** common mistake, which is very easy to do. Sadly Swift doesn't get the most useful of errors... For example, due to the same problem, I have had errors that a value is `"too ambiguous"` just because it couldn't detect that I didn't have `do-try-catch`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason why it is not inferring the closure type is because the `try` statement is not handled. This means that the closure expected to `"catch"` the error, but in your case, you forgot the `do-try-catch` rule.

Therefore you can try the following answer which will catch your errors:

```
do {
    let imageAsData = try Data(contentsOf: imageURL)
    let image = UIImage(data: imageAsData)
    let ImageObject = Image()
    ImageObject.image = image
    self.arrayOfImgObj.append(ImageObject)
} catch {
    print("imageURL was not able to be converted into data") // Assert or add an alert
}
```

You can then assert an error (for testing), or what I would personally do, is set up an alert.

This way the app wouldn't crash, but instead, notify the user. I find this **very** helpful when on the go and my device isn't plugged in - so I can see the error messages instead of a blank crash with no idea what happened.

Comment: What about the try statement not being handled causes this error?

Comment: @Outsider You need to use the do-try-catch pattern. If the `try` does not `catch` the error, then there is a *syntax error*. Xcode just couldn’t pick up what was wrong with the syntax in this case.

Answer (score 7):

This error can also happen if you have a non related compilation error in your closure body.  For example, you may be trying to compare two or more non-boolean types.

```
extension Array where Element == Resistance {
    init(_ points: [Point]) {
        let peaks = points.beforeAndAfter { (before, current, after) -> Bool in
            before < current && current > after
        }
        self = []
    }
}
```

will produce `Unable to infer closure type in the current context`.
The correct code:

```
extension Array where Element == Resistance {
    init(_ points: [Point]) {
        let peaks = points.beforeAndAfter { (before, current, after) -> Bool in
            before.value < current.value && current.value > after.value
        }
        self = []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to ScottyBlades answer, I'd like to add two data points to the "experience". It looks like referencing a non-existent property using `self` inside the block is not handled nicely by the compiler.

Nice error inside the block:

```
// Setting a handler for an NWListener instance:
self.nwListener?.newConnectionHandler = { (_ connection: NWConnection) -> Void in
    // Results in "Cannot find 'nonExistentProperty' in scope" 
    // in the line below:
    guard let delegate = nonExistentProperty else { return }
}
```

Weird "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" error: (note the new **self** in front of nonExistentProperty)

```
// Setting a handler for an NWListener instance:
// Results in "Type of expression is ambiguous without more context" 
// at the equals sign below:
self.nwListener?.newConnectionHandler = { (_ connection: NWConnection) -> Void in
    guard let delegate = self.nonExistentProperty else { return }
}
```